# Why PDFBox scan Fonts during Image Conversion (PDF to Png)

Tags: java, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I am getting these a lot of times in my application

```
o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont : No Unicode mapping for 28 (8) in font NSWQSF+TimesNewRoman,Bold
```

Because of this possibly my apllication is getting out of memory.
Can someone describe me why every page and all fonts in the pdf is kept in memory when using PDFBox pdf to image conersion?

My Code :

```
        PDDocument document = null;
        int pageCounter = 0;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(file);
            document.setResourceCache(new PDFBoxResourceCache());
            PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
            pdfRenderer.setSubsamplingAllowed(true);
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = null;
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
                ++pageCounter;
                try {
                    bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(pageCounter - 1, 300, ImageType.RGB);
                    outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bufferedImage, PAGE_FORMAT, outputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw e;
                } finally {
                    if (bufferedImage != null) {
                        bufferedImage.flush();
                        bufferedImage = null;
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null) {
                        try {
                            outputStream.close();
                            outputStream = null;
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            //
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                document.close();
            }
        }
```

Cache

```
    private class PDFBoxResourceCache extends DefaultResourceCache {
        @Override
        public void put(COSObject indirect, PDXObject xobject) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

Comment: for information, i have used all recommendations by pdfbox against outofmemory issue. cleared ResourceCache, used setSubSamplingMethod(true).

Comment: The "No Unicode mapping" warning is not related to memory problems. Please share the PDF and tell what -Xmx value you are using.

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr , Can you provide me any link or ur mail to drop the file in it. Since, our documents cannot be shared online.

Comment: Also, we are using google appengine. We specify the configuration in app.yaml. This is the configuration that we have. 
resources:
  cpu: 6
  memory_gb: 32.0

Comment: You can send the file to tilman at snafu dot de.

Comment: I have sent you the document @TilmanHausherr

Comment: I tried and it works with -Xmx1g. However your code did not define PAGE_FORMAT and PDFBoxResourceCache. I used png and an extension of DefaultResourceCache as described in the FAQ.

Comment: PAGE_FORMAT is PNG. 

I have Added the Cache block as well in the above snippet. Forgot to mention it here. It took more than 15 min at page 75 and then  it gave OOM error. Also, when debugging we found that this happened whle calling renderImageWithDPI method

Comment: It took 4 minutes on my machine (Ryzen 1700 on W10, energy saving mode). What jdk are you using? Make sure you are using a current one. Just for fun, I tried to let it run with -Xmx250m instead of -Xmx1g - that worked too.